DC latching relay
A positive 3 V DC pulse is to be applied to the coil of a 3 V DC magnetic latch relay in order to latch it.
Likewise, a negative 3 V DC pulse is to be applied to the coil to reset the relay.
Is there a simple way to generate these positive and negative pulses?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It sounds like what you want is a bistable latching relay. But your description is so vague ... I hesitate giving an answer in fear of the recent trend to down vote answers associated with closed or down voted questions.

This sounds like school work.  Please show us your circuit and we will comment on it.

Yes, there's a simple way, you need an H-bridge, which is 4 transistors arranged in a bridge configuration, in order to drive current one way or the other through the coil, plus 'off'.
Conceptually it is this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
For example, it can sit with A = B = 1 and no current will flow through the coil. Pulse A low and current will flow to the right through the coil. Pulse B low and current will flow to the left through the coil.
If the relay is a tiny low voltage/low power type you may be able to (ab)use a CMOS gate chip to drive it directly.
You can generate and time the pulses with whatever means you like, such as an MCU or even with analog means.

The positive / negative pulses may be generated in circuit by charging / discharging an electrolytic capacitor through the relay coil via an SPDT switch.
The pulse width is determined by the time constant (relay coil resistance * capacitance).
Here's the schematic.

